# How to determine which constraints or variable bounds are rendering a GAMS model infeasible?

Tags: optimization, nonlinear-optimization, gams-math

The solve summary in my GAMS model (NLP) is returning the following:

```
**** SOLVER STATUS     1 Normal Completion         
**** MODEL STATUS      19 Infeasible - No Solution
**** OBJECTIVE VALUE               NA
```

THE bounds on one of my variables are:

```
y.lo = 0, y.up = 0.15
```

if I change the bounds to:

```
y.lo = 0, y.up = 0.12
```

the model then converges and gives the following:

```
**** SOLVER STATUS     1 Normal Completion         
**** MODEL STATUS      2 Locally Optimal           
**** OBJECTIVE VALUE         66013164.0000
```

It turns out that the final variable level is

```
y.l = 0.12
```

how can it be that GAMS determined the model to be infeasible in the first case (upper bound = 0.15) even though the solution (0.12) was within the search space? (btw, I am using ANTIGONE solver)

Additionally, are there any methodical ways to identify which constraints/variable bounds are causing the model to be infeasible?

In order to find this (seemingly illogical) error, I had to spend hours guessing and checking arbitrary details within the model with no rhyme or reason. There has to be a better way, right?

Answer (score 0):

That issue is not GAMS fault, but the solver you're using. Have you tried with CONOPT?

You can see the infeasible constraint in the lst file. Some equations should have (***INFES) mark

Also, to solve your problem, I would try to provide the NLP solver an initial solution that is somehow close enough to the optimal one, or at least feasible.

I would also try to check the options of the solvers you are using to start the solution procedure with a feasible starting point.

Non-convex optimization is not easy.

I hope this helps.